# ASP.NET vNext in Visual Studio 2013 SP2

Tags: asp.net-core

I have install Visual Studio 2013 SP3. I can´t find project for ASP.NET vNext. These pages tell about vNext in Visual Studio SP2:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2014/05/12/mobile-first-cloud-first-development-visual-studio-apache-cordova-tooling-and-cloud-optimized-net-futures.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/05/12/visual-studio-2013-update-2-is-here.aspx

What I need install for vNext and cloud optimize mode work with VS 2013?

Comment: Visual Studio vNext CTP, http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/getting-started-with-aspnet-vnext-and-visual-studio You cannot find the necessary toolchain if you only have VS2013.

Comment: Thanks for reply, did you check first link? Why write about ASP.NET vNext in Visual Studio 2013 Update 2? ... I can´t install VS 2014 CTP2 on virtual machine and install it on my real pc side by side with VS 2010 is not recomended.

Comment: Sorry Pavel but the tooling for ASP.NET vNext is only available for Dev14. However, to develop, you actually don't need any VS - the runtime is available as separate packages (see the Home repo on github)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the first link talks about a few unrelated topics / products released by Microsoft. ASP.NET vNext is not available in VS2013. You could download Virtual Box (https://www.virtualbox.org/) which is free. Then install a trial version of Windows Server 2012 R2 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2012-r2) inside Virtual Box which is free to try for 180 days. Then install VS "14" on the guest machine. That way you don't have to buy anything and can still try VS "14" CTP 2. After the 180 days both the VS and Windows licence will expire so it makes no sense to keep the Virtual Box image anyway.